# This is the proof of the Anihilator?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\mathcal V$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-Vector space of finite dimension.
If $$x_1, x_2,...,x_m \in \mathcal V  \backslash\ \{0\}$$ 
Prove that exists $$f \in \mathcal V^* $$ such as $$ f(x_i)=0 $$ for all $$ i \in \mathcal {(1,...,m)}$$

I have this, i supposed that V has a basis $$(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$$ with $$m\leq n$$
And I took an arbitrary vector in  V and used the dual basis in this way
$$f(x_i)=f(a_1)f_1(x_i)+...+f(a_n)f_n(x_i)$$ then
$$x_i=a_i$$  for all $$ i \in \mathcal {(1,...,m)}$$

Then i extended the basis to $$ B =(x_1,x_2,...,x_m,...,a_n) $$ of V.

Then i used the theorem of building linear transformations and defined a linear transformation such $$f(A)=0$$ for all $$A \in \mathcal B$$ but $$ x_i $$ for all $$ i \in \mathcal {(1,...,m) \in \mathcal B}$$
 I don't know is it correct?

Comment: Why not simply take $f\equiv 0$? That’s not excluded by the proposition as you’ve stated it here.

Comment: But in this case  ≡ 0 belongs to V^*?

Comment: Yes. It’s the functional that returns $0$ for every vector.